# autohotkey trigger on windows+shift+right brings up start menu when key is released

Tags: autohotkey

If I have a command that fires on Windows + Shift + Right, the problem is that when I release the keys the start menu pops up. You can see it even with this script which should do nothing.  Is there a way to stop that from happening.

```
#+Right::Return
```

Comment: I think you're going to have to use GetKeyState.

Answer (score 0):

The start menu gets triggered on the release of the Win key. Though your test script works on my end (AHK_L v1.1.23.01) you can try adding this:

```
#+Right Up::return ; Do nothing on key release
```

Comment: That still triggers the start menu for me.  Maybe it is a Windows 10 thing?

Comment: Could be, i'll have a look later on my Win10 system at home.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it works:

```
#+Right::
KeyWait, LWin
; some stuff
Return
```

Comment: Still brings up the start menu - even as is - I didn't bother adding any "some stuff" yet :)

Answer (score 0):

This work in my case.

```
#H::     ;do something
#+H Up:: return

#RButton::     ;do something
#LButton Up::  Send {VKFF}
```

Just `return` or send another key to prevent it.